# Inputting data to a HashMap

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a Minecraft Server Plugin using the Bukkit Api.

Basically when my server stops, I use the onDisable() to store two hashmap contents to a config, then when the server starts, I use the onEnable() to take that info from the config and put it back in the HashMaps. That doesn't work.

Here are my methods: the saveBans is in the onDisable() and the loadBans is in the onEnable():

```
public class utilReloadSave {

static settingsmanager settings = settingsmanager.getInstance();


public static void saveBans() {
    ArrayList<String> bans = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (UUID play : Cooldown.cooldownPlayers.keySet()) {
        settings.getConfig().set("bans." + play, Cooldown.getTime(play, "TempBan"));
        bans.add(play.toString());
    }
    settings.getConfig().set("banlist", bans);
    settings.saveConfig();
}
public static void loadBans() {
    FileConfiguration config = settings.getConfig();
    ArrayList<String> bans = (ArrayList<String>) config.getStringList("banlist");
    for (String uuid : bans) {
        Cooldown.cooldownPlayers.put(UUID.fromString(uuid), new utilCooldown(UUID.fromString(uuid), config.getInt("bans." + uuid), System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
    config.set("bans", null);
    config.set("banlist", null);
    settings.saveConfig();
}
}
```

That seems to work. The problem is I use a onPlayerJoin Event:

```
@EventHandler
public void onLogin(PlayerLoginEvent e) {
    Player play = e.getPlayer();
    if (play.isBanned()) {
        if (Cooldown.isCooling(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan")) {

            File player = new File(basic.plugin.getDataFolder() + "/players/" + play.getUniqueId() + ".yml");
            FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(player);
            List<String> list = config.getStringList("banned.temp.reason");
            String reason = list.get(list.size()-1);

            if (Cooldown.getTime(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") < 60000L) {
                e.disallow(PlayerLoginEvent.Result.KICK_BANNED, ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You are still banned for " + Cooldown.getRemaining(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") + " seconds." + ChatColor.RED + " Reason: " + reason);
                return;}

            if (Cooldown.getTime(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") < 3600000L) {
                e.disallow(PlayerLoginEvent.Result.KICK_BANNED, ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You are still banned for " + Cooldown.getRemaining(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") + " minutes." + ChatColor.RED + " Reason: " + reason);
                return;}

            if (Cooldown.getTime(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") < 86400000L) {
                e.disallow(PlayerLoginEvent.Result.KICK_BANNED, ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You are still banned for " + Cooldown.getRemaining(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") + " hours." + ChatColor.RED + " Reason: " + reason);
                return;}

            e.disallow(PlayerLoginEvent.Result.KICK_BANNED, ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You are still banned for " + Cooldown.getRemaining(play.getUniqueId(), "TempBan") + " days." + ChatColor.RED + " Reason: " + reason);
            return;

        } else {
            File player = new File(basic.plugin.getDataFolder() + "/players/" + play.getUniqueId() + ".yml");
            FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(player);
            List<String> list = config.getStringList("banned.perm.reason");
            String reason = list.get(list.size()-1);
            e.disallow(PlayerLoginEvent.Result.KICK_BANNED, ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "You are permanentely banned! " + ChatColor.RED + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Reason: " + reason);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

which will check if there is something in the Hashmap but there isn't since it returns the else statement.

```
public static HashMap<UUID, utilCooldown> cooldownPlayers = new HashMap<UUID, utilCooldown>();

public static void add(UUID player, String ability, long seconds, long systime) {
    if(!cooldownPlayers.containsKey(player)) cooldownPlayers.put(player, new utilCooldown(player));
    if(isCooling(player, ability)) return;
    cooldownPlayers.get(player);
    utilCooldown.cooldownMap.put(ability, new utilCooldown(player, seconds * 1000, System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public static boolean isCooling(UUID player, String ability) {
    if(!cooldownPlayers.containsKey(player)) return false;
    if(!utilCooldown.cooldownMap.containsKey(ability)) return false;
    return true;
}

public static double getRemaining(UUID player, String ability) {
    if(!cooldownPlayers.containsKey(player)) return 0.0;
    if(!utilCooldown.cooldownMap.containsKey(ability)) return 0.0;
    return utilTime.convert((utilCooldown.cooldownMap.get(ability).seconds + utilCooldown.cooldownMap.get(ability).systime) - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.BEST, 1);
}

public static void removeCooldown(UUID key, String ability) {
    if(!cooldownPlayers.containsKey(key)) {
        return;
    }
    if(!utilCooldown.cooldownMap.containsKey(ability)) {
        return;
    }
    utilCooldown.cooldownMap.remove(ability);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void handleCooldowns() {
    if(cooldownPlayers.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    for(Iterator<UUID> it = cooldownPlayers.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        UUID key = it.next();
        cooldownPlayers.get(key);
        for(Iterator<String> iter = utilCooldown.cooldownMap.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String name = iter.next();
            if(getRemaining(key, name) <= 0.0) {
                OfflinePlayer p = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(key);
                p.setBanned(false);
                removeCooldown(key, name);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static long getTime(UUID player, String ability) {
    return (utilCooldown.cooldownMap.get(ability).seconds + utilCooldown.cooldownMap.get(ability).systime) - System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the simplest case that demonstrates your question.

Comment: sure you may not understand all of it though

Comment: i really need help...

Comment: Your problem is likely in `settingsmanager` which you haven't provided.  You _really_ need to do some interactive debugging (i.e. set breakpoints) to find out where things aren't working the way you expect.  We cannot help you with what you've provided so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison The problem isn't the settingsmanager, I can guarantee that... I did some more research and found out that the key in the HashMap cooldownPlayers is set, but not the value.. :/

Comment: The key is set but not the value? That doesn't make sense. I would ask whether you mean the value is `null`, except that all calls to `cooldownPlayers.put` use a constructor for the value argument and therefore can't be `null`. And why have you written `cooldownPlayers.get(key)`? (Twice.) This is a useless statement; surely you meant something like `utilCooldown ucd = cooldownPlayers.get(key)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume:

1. You have tested that the `ArrayList` in `loadBans` is not empty - before blaming the HashMap.
2. You have also checked whether or not these methods `loadBans` and `saveBans` are being called.
3. You have manually opened the config files to see what's in there.

You can use `Debug`-mode or extensively use `System.out.println(...)` for debugging. Whenever something is `null` or empty, while it shouldn't be - try to go back and see where it wasn't `null` or empty.

Comment: All done :/ I found the bug and now there's actually a value inputted but the time is multiplied by a certain huge-ass number :p (tes francais?)

Comment: The fact that part of your code says `currentTimeMillis`, and another part says `utilCooldown.cooldownMap.get(ability).seconds` for instance, has nothing to do with that? (non, je ne suis pas francais)